# Cucumber-JVM: Parallel execution not exactly parallel

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I had coded two features file and each of the features file open different browser URL for example one is open google.com and secnd one open amazon.com but this is not the case.

Bothe browsers open google.com. Moreover, it cannot interact with the browser, any actions coded to the browser is not get executed. Besides this, closing first browser cause second browser has null pointer exception.

Cucumber version 6 I start with AbstractCucumberTesNG inheritance. Then i create Login.Feature and follow by AddProduct.Feature.

The expected behaviour should be one browser open phptravels.net website and another browser open http://sellerceter.lazada.my.

This is not the case with my current situation where it open two browsers with phptravels.net, after cloing one browser it open seller.lazada website.

```
public class AddProduct {

    private WebDriverWait timeWait;
    private AddProductPageObject page;
    private ChromeDriver driver;
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(AddProduct.class);
    // ======================================================================
    public AddProduct() {
    }

    @Given("navigate to manage product")
    public void navigateToManageProduct() {
        log.info("Start Login");
        try {

            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver =  new ChromeDriver();
            this.timeWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, AddProductPageObject.class);
            driver.navigate().to("https://sellercenter.lazada.com.my/apps/seller/login");
            timeWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(page.getLazadaSellerLogo()));

            // Input username
            driver.findElement(page.getUsername()).click();
            driver.findElement(page.getUsername()).clear();
            driver.findElement(page.getUsername()).sendKeys("nicholaswkc34@gmail.com");

            // Input password
            driver.findElement(page.getPassword()).click();
            driver.findElement(page.getPassword()).clear();
            driver.findElement(page.getPassword()).sendKeys("wlx_+279295");

            // Click submit btn
            driver.findElement(page.getSignInButton()).click();

            //assertThat(page.getPageTitle())

            Wait wait = new Wait();
            wait.implicitWait(driver, 5);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

public class Login_FE {

```
private WebDriverWait timeWait;
private LoginPageObject page;
private ChromeDriver driver;
private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Login_FE.class);
// ======================================================================
public Login_FE() {
}

@Given("Launch the homepage and login")
public void launchTheHomepageAndLogin() {
    log.info("Start Login");
    try {

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver =  new ChromeDriver();
        timeWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        // Instantiate LoginPageObject
        page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageObject.class);
        log.info("Navigate to phptravels homepage");
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.phptravels.net/admin");
        timeWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(page.getPhpLogo()));

        Actions inputAct = new Actions(driver);
        inputAct.sendKeys("admin@phptravels.com").perform();
        driver.findElement(page.getUsername()).sendKeys("admin@phptravels.com");


        Wait wait = new Wait();
        wait.implicitWait(driver, 3);



    }catch(Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }



    log.info("Login Successfully");
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Im using the same concept for testing mobile apps. So in order to open 2 browsers and to interact with them separately you have to store the driver while initiating in a threadlocal like below :

```html
private static ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver<MobileElement>> appiumDriver = new ThreadLocal<>();
```